# No funcionan mis input tipo date en el explorador safari html

Tags: html, safari

espero se encuentren muy bien.
Mis input type="date" en html no funcionan en safari.

```
<form action="reporte.php" method="POST">
<td>Fecha Inicial:</td>
<td><input type='date' name='datoss' class="bot"></td>

<td>Fecha Final:</td>
<td><input type='date' name='datoss1' class="bot"></td>

<td><input type="submit" id="consul" class="client" value="Exportar">
</form>
```

En google chrome los mismos input despliegan un calendario y en safari no.

De que manera puedo hacer que funcionen en safari?

Saludos.

Comment: Todos los navegadores interpretan los campos date, time, number, etc de formas diferentes. Si quieres unificar esto, tendras que usar un datepicker personalizado, hay muchos por internet basados en jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me temo que Safari no tiene una **UI** implementada para los `<input type="date">`, por lo que, aunque sean compatibles (no te va a arrojar ningún error el navegador y vas a poder usarlos para recuperar datos e insertar datos) no se va a desplegar nada al pulsarlos.

Es preferible usar una librería externa, porque además de arrojar mejor compatibilidad, te quitas el problema de que cada navegador renderiza este tipo de campos a su manera.

Te recomiendo `datepicker` de **JQueryUI**.

```js
$( function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**Referencias:** [input date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date), [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Perfecto usare esa librería muchas gracias. saludos.